# using php for loop for mysqli_fetch_array

Tags: php, mysqli

I want to use `for` loop instead of using the conventional `while` loop

Like this one (psuedo code):

```
$list = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

for($x = 0; $x < sizeof($list); $x++){
    echo $x;
}
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Why not use `foreach` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no reason why you can't use a `while` loop. That being said, when you now use `sizeof($list)`, you will get the number of columns selected from the query (this `$list` variable has as many elements as columns was selected). You will therefor attempt to loop (and ouput the count of) the number of columns you fetched.

Instead, you might want to do something like this below - fetch the number of rows based on `mysqli_num_rows()`, which is exactly that - the number of rows returned by the query.

```
for ($x = 0; $x <= mysqli_num_rows($result); $x++) {
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    var_dump($row);
}
```

Although, the standard way - and in my opinion the best way - of doing it is via `while`.

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    var_dump($row);
}
```